# Interal wireless adapter VM

Tags: wireless, virtualbox, adapter

I want to search for wireless connections with my internal wireless adapter. My windows uses the ethernet cable. But I don't know how to setup up the wireless adapter for my ubuntu that it can search wireless connections in ubuntu itself.
Is this even possible?

Greetings.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the WiFi adapter in your computer available _to Ubuntu running in a VM_ ? If so, that's not possible. You can connect to WiFi on the host, and share it with the VM, but the OS in the VM cannot directly see the WiFi adapter or scan for networks.

Comment: Thank you. Are there other virtual machines programmes that support the thing I want?

Comment: No, generally, if you want to do things like scan for wireless networks and list them, you have to do that from the main OS. You cannot do it from within a VM, at least not with any software that I know of. However, if you have a USB WiFi adapter, you could use that with VirtualBox's USB passthrough.In fact, you _may_ be able to use the internal WiFi adaptor this way too - Google "VirtualBox PCI passthrough". However, this might not work, and if it does, you'll only be able to use the WiFi adapter in the guest OS in the VM - you can't share it with both the VM and host.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to actually scan and list wireless networks in the VM, or is it something else you want to achieve ? Maybe there's another way to get the end result you want.

Comment: I just want to test some hacking software and start as a script kiddie. Just to learn some stuff. I am pretty young so it could be usefull. I think I will set a partition on my ssd then. Does anybody now what a save way is to make a partition?

Comment: If you're installing Ubuntu side-by-side with Windows, the Ubuntu installer will create the partition for you.